# Parsing a URL, overriding parts, and putting it back together in Python

Tags: python, parsing, url

In my program, I want a user to be able to specify a url to a CouchDB database.

I want to provide sane defaults for parts of this URL; for example, localhost, 5984, and mushin are defaults for host, port, and path respectively.

urlparse.urlparse returns a tuple subclass that also has property accessors, but no setters.

host and port (and later on, username and password) are properties that parse the netloc part of the tuple.  These properties are get only though.  So this code, which would be ideal for me, fails:

```
   try:
        jane = urlparse(args[0])
    except IndexError:
        self.stdout.write('Please give a database to replicate with.\n')
        return

    if not jane.hostname:
        jane.hostname = HOST
    if not jane.port:
        jane.port = PORT
    if not jane.path:
        jane.path = DB

    url = jane.geturl()
```

Using the tuple interface doesn't help, because netloc is not split into username/password/host/port components, so I still have to do the brunt of the work myself.

Is there any better way to parse a URL, override pieces of it, and put back together a new URL ?

Answer (score 3):

A fragment I used to solve this issue:

```
netloc_regex = re.compile(r"(?:([^:]+)(?::(.*))?@)?([^:]+)(?::([\d]+))?")
endpoint = # some value

scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse(endpoint)
username, password, host, port = netloc_regex.search(netloc).groups()

# manipulate components here

auth = ":".join(filter(None, (username, password)))
address = ":".join(filter(None, (host, port)))
netloc = "@".join(filter(None, (auth, address)))
endpoint = urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment))
```

I expect there are bugs, and uncaught cases, such as it doesn't enforce that you must have a username if password is not `None`. But it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line using [yurl](https://github.com/homm/yurl/) library:

```
>>> import yurl
>>> user_url = yurl.URL('http://without.port/#hash')
>>> your_defaults = yurl.URL('//:33/default')  # or URL(port=33, path='/default')

>>> print user_url.replace(*map(lambda x: x or None, your_defaults))
http://without.port:33/default#hash
```

There `map` replaces empty parts (empty strings) with `None` and then pass as arguments to `user_url.replace()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [urlparse.urlunparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunparse) on a manipulated copy of the tuple.

> The parts argument can be any six-item iterable.

```
p = urlparse.urlparse(url)
l = list(p)
l[4] = "foo=bar" # manipulate query parameters
urlparse.urlunparse(l)
```

Comment: And how would you manipulate the copy of the tuple ? netloc can optionally contain host, port, username, and password, which is exactly the problem I'm asking about.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're not addressing the problem.  I know about urlparse/urlunparse; the question is, is there any functionality out there that can parse netloc, override some of the values, then put it back together.  That's why my post says: Using the tuple interface doesn't help, because netloc is not split into username/password/host/port components, so I still have to do the brunt of the work myself.

Comment: Parsing `netloc` to `login:passwd@host:port` should be easy. And, no, I don't know any better way.

Comment: Given that urlparse only handles 2 pieces that are interesting for this case (netloc and path), one of which is trivial, and one of which has 4 pieces, I'd say that this parsing is harder than what urlparse does.  I'm trying to avoid rolling my own code for something that would seem like a common use case.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DbUrl(object):

    def __init__(self, db_url):
        split = urlparse.urlparse(db_url)
        self.scheme = split.scheme
        self.hostname = split.hostname
        self.port = split.port
        self.username = split.username
        self.password = split.password
        self.database = split.path.lstrip('/')

    def __str__(self):
        auth = ":".join(filter(None, (self.username, self.password)))
        address = ":".join(filter(None, (self.hostname, str(self.port))))
        netloc = "@".join(filter(None, (auth, address)))
        return urlparse.urlunparse((self.scheme, netloc, self.database, '', '', ''))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%s)' % (self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join(
            '%s=%r' % (attr_name, attr_value)
            for attr_name, attr_value in self.__dict__.iteritems()))

    def replace(self, **kwargs):
        db_url = copy.copy(self)
        for attr_name, attr_value in kwargs.iteritems():
            assert attr_name in db_url.__dict__, 'Unknown attribute'
            setattr(db_url, attr_name, attr_value)
        return db_url
```

and the usage:

```
>>> DbUrl('postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5433/postgres').replace(password='****')
DbUrl(username='username', password='****', hostname='127.0.0.1', database='postgres', scheme='postgresql', port=5433)
>>> str(DbUrl('postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5433/postgres').replace(password='****'))
'postgresql://username:****@127.0.0.1:5433/postgres'
>>> str(DbUrl('postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5433/postgres').replace(password=None))
'postgresql://username@127.0.0.1:5433/postgres'
>>>
```